# SFML CircleShape movement not working

Tags: c++, sfml

I am trying to generate 10 circles at random positions and locations across the screen in SFML. For some reason since adding events the movement isn't working (not sure if the use of rand is causing an issue).

The events represent 2 different modes, where in one the circles should bounce off the screen bounds, and in the second they should reappear at a random position and velocity. The circles simply flicker and then reappear at random locations, and never more than 5-6 of them.

I've tried both drawing the circles inside and outside of the events thinking I wasn't understanding the events process. There's nothing to keep track of time elapsed, but I've written another fully functional SFML program that works with almost the exact same code and without use of the clock, the only difference being there's only one circle being moved.

```
float SIZE = 750;

struct Stone
{
    sf::CircleShape st;
    sf::Vector2f velocity;

    Stone(float x, float y, float p1, float p2)
    {

        sf::Vector2f velocity (x,y);
        st.setRadius(stoneRadius);
        st.setFillColor(sf::Color::Black);
        st.setOrigin(stoneRadius, stoneRadius);
        st.setPosition(p1, p2);
    }

   ....

    void update_bounce()
    {

        st.move(velocity);

        if (st.getPosition().x - stoneRadius <= 0)
            velocity.x = -velocity.x;
        else if ((st.getPosition().x + stoneRadius) >= SIZE)
            velocity.x = -velocity.x;


        if (st.getPosition().y - stoneRadius <= 0)
            velocity.y = -velocity.y;
        else if (st.getPosition().y + stoneRadius >= SIZE)
            velocity.y = -velocity.y;
    }


    void update()
    {

        srand ( time(NULL) );

        st.move(velocity);

        if ( (st.getPosition().x - stoneRadius) <= 0 || (st.getPosition().x + stoneRadius) <= SIZE
                || (st.getPosition().y - stoneRadius) <= 0 || (st.getPosition().y - stoneRadius >= SIZE) )
        {

            float v = rand() % 4 + (6);
            float p1 = rand () % 1500 + (-750);
            float p2 = rand () % 1500 + (-750);

            velocity.x = v;
            velocity.y = v;
            st.setPosition(p1, p2);
        }

    }
};

...


int main()
{
    srand ( time(NULL) );

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(SIZE, SIZE), "test");

     window.setFramerateLimit(30);

 ...

    vector<Stone> gameStones;

                for (int x = 0; x< 10; x++) {
                    float v =  rand() % 12 + (-6);
                    float p1 = rand() % 1500 + (-750);
                    float p2 = rand() % 1500 + (-750);
                    gameStones.push_back(Stone(v,v,p1,p2));
                    }


    while(window.isOpen())
    {

        sf::Event event;

        while (window.pollEvent(event))

            {

            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Q)

            {

                window.close();
                break;
            }

            else if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::R)

            {
               for(i=0; i<10; i++)
                gameStones[i].update();


                ....

                 }

            }


            else if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::B)

            {

                for(i=0; i<10; i++)
                 gameStones[i].update_bounce();

                ....


                }


            }


        window.clear(sf::Color::White);

        window.draw(gameStones[0].st);
                window.draw(gameStones[1].st);
                window.draw(gameStones[2].st);
                window.draw(gameStones[3].st);
                window.draw(gameStones[4].st);
                window.draw(gameStones[5].st);
                window.draw(gameStones[6].st);
                window.draw(gameStones[7].st);
                window.draw(gameStones[8].st);
                window.draw(gameStones[9].st);

  ...

        window.display();

        }

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please concretize the question.

Comment: ctor doesnt set the velocity member variable....